# Lua C modules: confused about including members

Tags: c, lua

I am trying to register a Lua C module that I need to use like this.

```
local harfbuzz = require 'harfbuzz'

-- initialize blob
local blob = harfbuzz.Blob.new(…)
print(blob:length())
```

My understanding is that I should create a new table and add a metatable to it with the methods, and then add that table as a member `Blob` to the top-level lib table.

Here is the relevant snippet of code in my C file. I am not very sure what to include in the `register_blob` function. I tried a few things and they did not work.

```
static const struct luaL_Reg blob_methods[] = {
  { "length", blob_length },
    {"__gc", blob_destroy },
  { NULL, NULL },
};

static const struct luaL_Reg blob_functions[] = {
  { "new", blob_new },
  { NULL,  NULL }
};

static const struct luaL_Reg lib_table [] = {
  {"version", get_harfbuzz_version},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

int register_blob(lua_State *L) {
  // QUESTION: What should I include here
}

int luaopen_luaharfbuzz (lua_State *L) {
  lua_newtable(L);

  register_blob(L);

  luaL_setfuncs(L, lib_table, 0);

  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `register_blob` does really depends on what `new_blob` needs to do. The two feed into one another.

Given your use case, `new_blob` needs to create new objects, and those new objects have metatable members equal to your `blob_methods` table. So, what `new_blob` needs to do is:

1. Create a table/userdata to be returned.
2. Assign that table/userdata a metatable built from the contents of `blob_methods` table.
3. Do whatever other initialization work is needed on the object.
4. Return the object.

So what your `register_blob` code needs to do is build the metatable that you intend to use in step 2, then store it somewhere that `new_blob` can easily access it. But also somewhere that *noone else can*. Or at least, noone outside of C code.

Lua being well designed, it has a place for storing exactly this kind of data. It's called the [Lua registry table](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.5). The registry acts like a global table. But it can only be access from C; Lua code can't touch it (well, unless you use the debug library. Or pass the registry table to Lua).

The idiomatic way (as I understand it) that the registry is used is that every C module stakes out its own table index in the registry. So your `luaopen_luaharfbuzz` function would create a table and store that into a key in the registry. The key would probably some string, likely named after your module. And you put all your private stuff into that table.

So your `register_blob` function would:

1. Create the table that will be used as the metatable for `blob` objects.
2. Use `luaL_setfuncs` to set the `blob_methods` into the newly created table.
3. Get the `harfbuzz` table from the registry.
4. Put the newly created table into a known key in the `harfbuzz` table from the registry.

That way, `new_blob` knows exactly where to go to get the metatable to use.

Comment: Thanks for writing such a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Of course you can pass the registry to Lua: `lua_pushvalue(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX)`. This is what `debug.getregistry` does ...

Comment: @siffiejoe: Noted and fixed.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That was fast ... ;-)

Comment: @NicolBolas can you check the updated code above in `register_blob`. Does that look alrite? I am still have issues when I do this multiple times to register multiple classes like Blob, Face etc.

Comment: @vyom: You're not supposed to update your question so that it has the answer within it. That makes it impossible for someone to understand what your problem was, which means your question is only helpful to you and nobody else.

Comment: Fair enough. Should I undo it?

Comment: Alternatively – I could rollback, and then add a section at the _end_ of my question explicitly stating that it was added later.